# get a variable from within struct in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

get a variable from within struct in swift 5 :

i want to get  `EResults` from inside  GetSystemCats !

and i want to put it inside array

```py
struct GetSystemCats {
    var responseCode: Int?
    var message: String?
    var status: Bool?
    var results: [EResults]

    public init(response: [String: Any]) {
        self.responseCode = response["responseCode"] as? Int
        self.message = response["message"] as? String
        self.status = response["status"] as? Bool
        let results = response["results"] as! [[String: Any]]
        self.results = []
        for item in results {
            let result = EResults(result: item)
            self.results.append(result)
        }
    }
}

struct EResults {

    var title: String?
    var id: Int?
    var sub_category: [Category]


    public init(result: [String: Any]) {

        self.title = result["title"] as? String
        self.id = result["id"] as? Int
        let sub_category = result["sub_category"] as! [[String: Any]]
        self.sub_category = []
        for item in sub_category {
            let result = Category(response: item)
            self.sub_category.append(result)
        }



    }
}



struct Category {
    var title: String?
    var id: Int?

      public init(response: [String: Any]) {
        self.title = response["title"] as? String
        self.id = response["id"] as? Int

    }

}
```

I use it to display the `title` of the `Category` in the table view

Please help me!!

Comment: So you've got something like `let systemCats = GetSystemCats(response: someJSONData)` and you want to access `systemCats.results` ?

Comment: ok and i want  ```EResults```

Comment: how to get this ?

Comment: Also, since you mention Swift 5, I recommend looking into `Codable` - there are many references (e.g. https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/codable, https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet)

Comment: `systemCats.results` *is* an array of `EResults` - if that's not what you want, I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: i want to put it inside  ` ` `Category ` ` ` to get the titel !

Comment: i want to put it inside ` Category `  like ` EResults `

Comment: As written, a `GetSystemCats` has zero or more `EResults`s. An `EResults` has zero or more `Category`s. You want a `Category` to have the same `.title` as the `EResults` it belongs to?

Comment: yas i want !! !

Comment: you can help me last

Comment: Does the code I've posted below do what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

To give every `Category` awareness of the `.title` of the `EResults` it belongs to, simply pass it to the initialiser:

```
struct EResults {

    var title: String?
    var id: Int?
    var sub_category: [Category]


    public init(result: [String: Any]) {

        self.title = result["title"] as? String
        self.id = result["id"] as? Int
        let sub_category = result["sub_category"] as! [[String: Any]]
        self.sub_category = []
        for item in sub_category {
            let result = Category(response: item, in: self)
            self.sub_category.append(result)
        }
    }
}

struct Category {
    var eresultTitle: String?
    var title: String?
    var id: Int?

      public init(response: [String: Any], in eResult: EResults) {
        self.eresultTitle = eResult.title
        self.title = response["title"] as? String
        self.id = response["id"] as? Int
    }
}
```

NOTE: As general advice, I thoroughly recommend looking into `Codable` as it will let you get rid of all those optional vars - immutable structs are generally preferred and will save you a lot of unwrapping and the need to provide default values (e.g. ugly code like `thing.label.text = category?.title ?? "unknown"`). Your requirement for `Category`s to know the `.title` of it's parent `EResult` would be slightly awkward though.